# Firestore distributed counters: How to know the ideal shards sum we need?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

TL;DR:  **Is there any maths here to predict exactly how many shards should I use for my counters?**

I'm a big fan of counters (yeah that's weird) and I'm writing a small polls app.

I have **counters** collection where each document is a **counter** and each counter has a sub-collection of **shards**.

```
<root_level>
├── [counters]
│   └── counterID
│       ├── num_shards: 20
│       └── [shards]
│           ├── 1
│           │   └── counts: 2
│           ├── 2
│           │   └── counts: 7
│           └── 3...
├── [votes]
    └── voteId
        ...
```

Also, I've set up a Cloud Function to track any new added **vote** document inside a **votes** collection. This function get a random shard ID and increment it... just like the example in the documentation.

```
const counterRef = db.doc('counters/counter')

export const onVote = functions.firestore
  .document('votes/{voteId}')
  .onCreate(async snapShot => {
    const counterDoc = (await counterRef.get())

    const { num_shards } = counterDoc.data()
    const shard_id = Math.floor(Math.random() * num_shards).toString()
    const shard_ref = counterRef.collection('shards').doc(shard_id)

    return db.runTransaction(async tsx => {
      const shardDoc = (await tsx.get(shard_ref))
      const oldCount = shardDoc.data().count
      return tsx.update(shard_ref, { count: oldCount + 1 })
    })
  })
```

And in my client, I have combined two observables: one for the counter and one for it's related shards sub-collection, and I do a basic reduce() to sum the total count.

```
combineLatest(counter$, shards$)
      .pipe(
        map(([counter, shards]) => {
          const count = shards.reduce(
            (acc: any, shards: any) => shards.count + acc,
            0
          )

          return { ...counter, count }
        })
      )
      .subscribe(counter => /* display counter */)
```

Well, I did several tests with 5, 10, 15 shards and 1000 votes and I'm getting data contention errors. But with 100 shards, I got no errors. But it seems like this is a coin-flip game. In fact, sometimes it just work with few shards, sometimes I need more shards.

So my question is: **Is there any maths here to predict exactly how many shards should I use for my counters?** I'd like to have the best performance for the lowest cost.

[image: Data contention errors]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to predict what your maximum load is going to be, and shard according to that load.  A document can handle a sustained [1 write per second](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions) without generating an error that rejects the write.  So, if you want to be able to handle 50 writes per second, you will need *at least* 50 documents to shard across, assuming that the writes are perfectly distributed among them.  If you don't want to assume perfect distribution, go higher to reduce the chances of a single document being over-stressed with writes.

If you don't know your max load ahead of time, then you won't be able to optimize the number of document shards to use.  In that case, you will need to go arbitrarily high, and hope that it meets your actual needs.

Comment: I am using firebase and feeling that firebase is not complete solution for mobile apps (like, realtime counter). @Doug suggest, 50 document shards but its very costly.

Overall, firebase is costly + not complete solution. 

As per my knowledge, Firebase doesn't contains some necessary features including Counters (write limit), Real time search, random document etc. All these features are very basic, I think.

Comment: what would a firebase alternative be?